# Pyspark UDF not working, expecting string not column

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have written a UDF function that takes in a column and then parses the string into a datetime formatted string for all the values in that column.

However when I run the spark job, my function is throwing following error:

```
strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Column
```

```
Here is my UDF and python function

dateformat = udf(lambda x: datetimeformat(x), StringType())

def datetimeformat(x):
   return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

How the udf is called

newdf=newdf.withColumn("date",dateformat(newdf["date"]))
```

Comment: you need to define`datetimeformat` before you define `dateformat`. Just switch the order and you should be fine. By the way, there's a function [`pyspark.sql.functions.date_format`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) that you may find useful.

Comment: @pault I made the ordering change but the error still persisits. 
That function is able to parse a raw string with format like: '20180321 12:39:42.595000' and convert to timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not have visibility to your newdf. I created a temp data set like the following

c:\tmp\f4.csv

```
dt
20180212 15:10:10.000
20180212 15:10:10.000
20180212 15:10:10.000
```

Code is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime
schema=StructType([StructField("dt",StringType())])
f1=spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").load("c:/tmp/f4.csv")
dateformat = udf(lambda x: datetimeformat(x), StringType())
def datetimeformat(x):
   return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')



f2=f1.withColumn("date",dateformat(f1["dt"]))
f2.show()
```

Output

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  dt|                date|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|20180212 15:10:10...|2018-02-12 15:10:...|
|20180212 15:10:10...|2018-02-12 15:10:...|
|20180212 15:10:10...|2018-02-12 15:10:...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this example. Turns out I was calling my python function in another place that triggered that error.

Answer (score 0):

I can not test as I dont have a spark environment available but I think you just need to write the name of the column instead of the column object:

```
newdf=newdf.withColumn("date",dateformat("date"))
```